# Get user Location/Hometown through Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the **location/hometown** (whichever available) using the facebook graph API?

The **catch here is** I do not want the user to go through an authentication process, meaning I want to get the location/hometown **without** having the access_token

Therefore, the following case would be void 
https://graph.facebook.com/USERID?fields=location,hometown&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

Please help

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

access token is required with the following permissions

```
user_hometown

user_location
```

Answer (score 1):

use `hometown_location`  field of a user table to get location details. We get this info. only if a user shares it's location detail public.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the permissions to access this user data, you just have to parse the key-value dict to your model, eg:

```
self.user.location = [user objectForKey:@"location"][@"name"];
```

same for hometown:

```
self.user.hometown = [user objectForKey:@"hometown"][@"name"];
```

Regards.